# Can someone help me in Implementing XSSFilter

Tags: aem

Can someone help me in Implementing XSSFilter, I need to check for XSS vulnerabilities in AEM code, I found that its method boolean `check(ProtectionContext context, String src)`, checks for any XSS infected code, however what will be its context ? It would be nice if someone can share some example.

```
xssfilter=resourceResolver.adaptTo(XSSFilter.class);
String validjsonString = xssfilter.filter(jsonString);
LOGGER.debug("validjsonString:::::", validjsonString);

String[] uuidArray = getUUIDArray(validjsonString);
```

Comment: I have been working with AEM for quite some time now and never had to do something like this by myself. The XSS filter usually does its job in the background, for example in HTL templates it works out-of-the-box. Why do you need to do this? Maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: Hi jens, In a report generated from vulnerability detection tool, some of the java classes get caught, and it shows that the variable that is coming to a servlet goes unchecked, and it is used further in the code, However OOTB functionality checks the output to the HTL and not input to the backend. Also I have checked that XSS protection is enabled at dispatcher level, but I need to be double sure that attack does not cross the dispatcher, It would be really helpful if you share some knowledge on that.

Comment: I am not a security expert, but usually most variants of XSS are some variation of reflected XSS, were something is stored in your database and then displayed to other users (in their browser) and then doing something "evil", or someone tries to inject something that runs a script from a remote source or downloads something on your system etc. There are more XSS attacks, but those are probably the most popular. Reflected XSS attacks should be mitigated if you use HTLs display context and otherwise you should check user input that is going into XPath/JCR SQL(2) queries.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are using the non-depracted Sling APIs here. In this case the `ProtectionContext` you are missing is coming from the following `enum`:

```
org.apache.sling.xss.ProtectionContext
```

The `enum` has two values:

**HTML_HTML_CONTENT**

> Escape HTML for use inside element content (rules #6 and - to some degree - #1), using a policy to remove potentially malicous HTML

**PLAIN_HTML_CONTENT**

> Escape plain text for use inside HTML content (rule #1)

Those rules mentioned in those definitions can be found here:

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

So you could do either:

```
xssfilter.check(ProtectionContext.HTML_HTML_CONTENT, <your-string>);
xssfilter.check(ProtectionContext.PLAIN_HTML_CONTENT, <your-string>);
```

See: https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling11/org/apache/sling/xss/ProtectionContext.html#HTML_HTML_CONTENT

Comment: Hi Jens, I really appreciate your help.